# Comparing Dates within the same Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am having am issue comparing dates within the same dataframe /column.

I have Order data and Call data within the same dataframe.

I am trying to compare the START time of the order to the START time of the call.

If the call START time is within 30 days of Order Creation, I want to add the value in columns Tag_x and Tag_z to the call rows (last two rows in attached file).

If we have more than one "Order created"  value, I want to add Tag_x and Tag_z to the call rows (in the following format: Tagx1,  Tagx2...)

Attached is a sample of the data.

| CASE ID | Activity Name | START | minit_source_system | Tag_x | Tag_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Order created | Tuesday, March 16, 2021 | NC | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Open | Tuesday, March 16, 2021 | FWDS | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Job - COMPLETE | Tuesday, March 16, 2021 | FWDS | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Completed | Thursday, March 18, 2021 | FWDS | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Order created | Wednesday, May 4, 2022 | NC | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Open | Wednesday, May 4, 2022 | FWDS | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Job - COMPLETE | Wednesday, May 4, 2022 | FWDS | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Completed | Thursday, May 5, 2022 | FWDS | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Bill Issued | Tuesday, May 10, 2022 |  |  |  |
| 111 | Call Start | Tuesday, May 17, 2022 | Gen |  |  |
| 111 | PureFibre-TS | Tuesday, May 17, 2022 | Gen |  |  |

Desired Output:

| CASE ID | Activity Name | START | minit_source_system | Tag_x | Tag_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Order created | Tuesday, March 16, 2021 | NC | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Open | Tuesday, March 16, 2021 | FWDS | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Job - COMPLETE | Tuesday, March 16, 2021 | FWDS | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Completed | Thursday, March 18, 2021 | FWDS | Home Phone Installation | VOICE |
| 111 | Order created | Wednesday, May 4, 2022 | NC | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Open | Wednesday, May 4, 2022 | FWDS | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Job - COMPLETE | Wednesday, May 4, 2022 | FWDS | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Fielded Work Order Completed | Thursday, May 5, 2022 | FWDS | Home Security Installation | SECURITY |
| 111 | Bill Issued | Tuesday, May 10, 2022 |  |  |  |
| 111 | Call Start | Tuesday, May 17, 2022 | Gen | Home Phone Installation, Home Security Installation | VOICE, SECURITY |
| 111 | PureFibre-TS | Tuesday, May 17, 2022 | Gen | Home Phone Installation, Home Security Installation | VOICE, SECURITY |

I have tried splitting the data into two separate data frames (order and calls) and iterating through the rows. However, I am not sure I am using iterrows() correctly.

```
dfcall= df[df['Activity Name']=="Call Start"]
dfcall['Tag_x']=nan
dfcall['Tag_z']=nan
dfcall=dfcall[['CASE ID','Activity Name','START','Tag_x','Tag_z']].reset_index(drop=True)
dforder=df[df['Activity Name']=="Order created"].reset_index(drop=True)
dforder=dforder[['CASE ID','Activity Name','START','Tag_x','Tag_z']].reset_index(drop=True)

for index, row_c in dfcall.iterrows():
for index, row_o in dforder.iterrows():
    if (row_c['CASE ID']==row_o['CASE ID']) & (row_c['START']>row_o['START'])& (((row_c['START'] - row_o['START']).total_seconds()/60/60)<=720): 
        y=row_o['Tag_x']
        row_c['Tag_x']=y+" "+"|"+" "+row_o['Tag_x']
```

Comment: Please show your code